# iOS 4: Is it possible to show Local Notifications during a Telephony Call?

Tags: ios, ios4, uilocalnotification, core-telephony

I want an app run in the background and listen to the events that indicate initiated Telephony Calls (by using CTCallCenter). Upon this data, I want to register Local Notifications that indicate call duration. Is it possible to:

A: Listen to Telephony events in the background? How to keep the app from being suspended (Apple documentation states that events are not received while app is suspended)

B: Register Local Notifications upon this date and SHOW these notification DURING a call (or does the framework restrict Local Notifications during phone calls? I can't find any info on this)

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: kind of...  you can get call state events IF you have a background task active.  The bad news is that the background task will only last 10 min's.  So after the 10 min's you don't get any more call states.

B: Yes local notifications do work while on a call.  I've done it and it works just fine.